# How to convert VARCHAR2 to FLOAT in select statement in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select mudel 
from mudel 
where 50 > TO_NUMBER(voimsus)
```

> ERROR: ORA-01722: invalid number

`Voimsus` is a float number ex. 50.21 but datatype is `VARCHAR2`. Any idea how to convert it. Also I cant change datatype because there is data and there are child records.

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXSzN.png)

[Datatypes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKoyK.png)

**SOLUTION**: I changed every comma to decimal with

```
UPDATE mudel 
SET voimsus = REPLACE(voimsus, ',', '.') 
WHERE voimsus LIKE '%,%'
```

and it worked

Comment: Please provide sample data.

Comment: Either there is at least 1 row where the value in the `voimsus` column is not actually numeric or your session's `nls_numeric_characters` are set to expect the comma rather than the decimal point as the decimal separator.  The text of your question uses a decimal point.  The image you posted (please post data as text not images, preferrably in the form of `insert` statements that replicate the problem) appears to use the comma as the decimal separator.  What does your session use as the default decimal separator?

Comment: @JustinCave Is there any command so I can change every comma to decimal point?

Comment: How many rows you have in this table? Some of the rows have text character(s) so Oracle database is not able to convert it to a number. You could check for problem data using this query `select mudel from mudel where regexp_like (voimsus, '[A-Za-z]+');`

Comment: @PankajSaini I executed this command and it says no data found. There are like 40-50 rows and I just manually checked every value is "**,**"

Comment: I am pretty sure that when I could change comma to dot then it would work. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Here is how to find the rows where voimsus cannot be converted to number: `select * from mudel where voimsus is not null and to_number(voimsus default null on conversion error) is null;`. But why store numbers as strings in the first place? This just invites trouble.

Comment: OK. In that case you could do something like this `select mudel from mudel where 50 > to_number(replace(voimsus, ',', ''));`

Comment: You have updated your request with the "solution" to replace the comma with a dot in your data. This works for your session now. Next time someone starts with a session that has the comma for decimal separator, shall they change all the rows in the table again? Do you want to change the table data before every query in order to play safe? This is no solution at all, but a dirty workaround. Store numeric data in numeric columns instead.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your session's `nls_numeric_characters` setting specifies that a period is your decimal separator and a comma is your grouping separator (i.e. it has a `value` of ".,")

```
select * 
  from nls_session_parameters 
 where parameter = 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS'
```

while the data in your table uses a comma as the decimal separator, that would be the problem.  You could specify the NLS parameters you want to use in your `to_number` call

```
create table my_table( incorrect_data_type varchar2(10) );

insert into my_table( incorrect_data_type ) values( '123,45');

select to_number( incorrect_data_type, 
                  '9999D99', 
                  q'{nls_numeric_characters=',.'}') 
  from my_table;
```

Or you could change your session's settings

```
alter session set nls_numeric_characters = ',.'

select to_number( incorrect_data_type) from my_table;
```

Of course, if you solve the problem by changing your session's settings, that means that when you (or someone else) starts a new session, they'll need to change their session's settings as well (assuming they use the same NLS settings to establish the connection that you are).

The right answer, of course, is to use the correct data type for the column in the first place.  Storing numeric data in a character column is going to cause plenty of grief-- this is just one of the ways that tends to go wrong.  Fixing the data type now will save you lots of grief down the line.

Here's [a fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=edaab7ccf9696f7d084f709096f6d4ca) showing the options working (and failing).

Answer (score 1):

When converting strings to numbers, then don't rely on session settings by merely using

```
to_number(voimsus)
```

but specify the format stored in the string. For this you must tell the DBMS what the decimal separator is with `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS`. E.g.:

```
TO_NUMBER(voimsus, '9999999999D.99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.''')
```

But well, it is of course much better not to store numbers in string columns in the first place. Use a proper number type such as `NUMBER(12,2)` instead. (And I recommend not to use any float data type, such as (`BINARY_FLOAT`), because then your stored numbers are not exact, but approximate, e.g. 1.3 may be stored as something like 1.3000001).